# How to design table when have two table reference single column in another table

Tags: mysql

I am confusing about how to design table when have two table reference single column in another table.

For example, I have two type of user ( lets call them `user1` and `user2` ) because these two type user have multiple different information so I create two table for each of them, and each user have one account to login to system. So I create a table call account and let two table `user1` and `user2` reference to ID in table account. So when I have one account and I want to know which one this account belong to. It's quite inconvenient because I have to look for in two table.

Does it have solution for this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an entity `user`, create just one table `user` for them.

A user is a user, no matter if he has some special role. There will be some common fields for all users, e.g. a name.

```
table user:
user id 
user name 
age
homepage
```

To have specific information for different types of users, you create specialisation table with information about these roles:

```
table role1:
user id
roleinfo1
roleinfo2

table role2:
user id
roleinfo3
roleinfo4
roleinfo5
```

This way, a user can have multiple roles at the same time, but you can of course limit them to just one.

If a user can only be one of those roles (that's called disjunct), you have the additional statndard way to add a column `role` to your user-table and put all the information side-by-side in the user table, leaving the ones that don't belong to the user-role `null`:

```
table user:
user id 
user name 
age
homepage
roletype

roleinfo1
roleinfo2

roleinfo3
roleinfo4
roleinfo5
```

Even if the user can belong to multiple classes and in case there is no overlap between the additional columns, you can of course use the last approach and add multiple flags (e.g. columns `istype1` and  `istype2`), though this is a non-standard-approach.

**Update** Just to clarify how you use the first solution: every user has an entry in table `user`, e.g. with `user id = 1`. This also makes sure that no user of roles user1 and user2 can have the same user id.
`User id` in the role tables is both primary key and a foreign key of the user table.

To make that user a user of role 1, you then add an entry to table `role 1` with `user id = 1`. If he is (also) a user of role 2, you add an entry to table role2 with `user id = 1`.

You can join the tables to get the "whole" picture,

```
select * from user
left join role1 on user.`user id` = role1.`user id`
left join role2 on user.`user id` = role2.`user id`
```

This will, apart from the double id columns (that will basically can be treated as the marker `istype1`, `istype2` in the comment to the seconds solution) and the missing role-column look exactly like the second method with just one table.

To check if user with `user id = 1` is of role 1, you can check if `role1.user id` is `null` in this query, or check if `user id = 1` is in table `role1`. To e.g. list all data for just role 1, you can use

```
select * from user join role1 on user.`user id` = role1.`user id`
```

(it uses a join instead of the left join, since and entry for role 1 has to exist).

In most cases you don't even need the specialized data, so you can just join your `account`-table with the `user`-table. In any case, you never have to worry about checking two tables (or even more, if you decide to add a 3rd kind of user).

Comment: thank you. I am thinking about create two table for each type of user and create a view for some common attribute between two table. what is the weak point of this approach ?

Comment: @oopaewem The week point of your approach is that a) it has NO, really absolutely NO advantage over the correct approach b) you cannot make sure users in table1 and 2 don't have the same user id c)  you cannot use userid as a foreign key for any table d) this kind of problem you have right now will bite you in the *** every time you are trying to join userdata with other data - you will always have to check two tables e) adding more roles is harder f) if you absolutely want to have 2 "tables" for some reason, create views user1 and user2 from user g) you might just want to trust us it is wrong

Comment: i understand it now. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Whats the point of the account table? If each user has one account, why don't you store the account columns in the User table.

Furthermore you can still make a parent user table for the columns they share and then make childtables for the specific users.

for example

Parent: User

Children: Employee/Customer

Comment: but when i have a parent how can i find it's child ? i still have to look for in two table ?

Comment: You cant, the parent doesn't even know he has childs, but the child knows whos his parent. 
Maybe give an usecase what do you exactly want to accomplish. 
From my example if you want an User whos a Customer you call the Customer table, if you want a Employee you, the Employee table